# How to make a button that will uncheck all checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have this code that is possible to check/uncheck all checkboxes and check/uncheck a single checkbox.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Persist checkboxes</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <label for="checkAll">Check all</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option1">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option2">
</div>
<div>
  <label for="option3">Option 3</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="option3">
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $("#checkAll").on("change", function() {
    $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
    var checkboxValues = {};
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
      checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
  });

  function repopulateCheckboxes(){
    var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
    if(checkboxValues){
      Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
        var checked = checkboxValues[element];
        $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
      });
    }
  }

  $.cookie.json = true;
  repopulateCheckboxes();
</script>
```

My question is that I want to make a button that will have a function that will clear or uncheck all checkboxes. Could some help me do that? Thanks!

Comment: $(':checkbox') is not valid. Use **$('input[type="checkbox"]')**

Comment: @AdrianPreuß `:checkbox` is a checkbox filter jQuery provides.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calling the following function on button click will do:

```
function uncheckAll(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('checked',false);
}
```

```js
function uncheckAll() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").prop("checked", false)
}
$(':button').on('click', uncheckAll)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='button' value="clear" />
```

---

**Pure JS version**:

```js
function uncheckAll() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .forEach(el => el.checked = false);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', uncheckAll)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' />
<input type='checkbox' checked/>
<button>Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<button type="reset">Uncheck all</button>
```

Comment: This works to clear the checkmarks, but does not trigger the change event on the checkboxes. I added an "onclick" function to the button to make the changes I needed.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple and fast**

http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/Zq6Et/

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",false);
});
```

Comment: this will loop through all check boxes whether its checked or not. my existing answer should be faster..

Comment: that's also true for `:checked`, jquery not only loop through all checkboxes and check whether this is checked or not but create another array and save the checked ones in that array..so that mean it's computationally more expensive. Just because it's done by jquery doesn't mean it's magically no matter of concern.

Comment: beside either way it's a matter of like 10ms..unless there are 30,000..checkboxes that get checked on and off per second!! there is no value in this optimization.

Comment: good point. Anyway jquery will loop through all checkboxes. BUT in this case it has to set all of their checked attributes to false -  which is an overhead.
Second point - in this case, agreed.

Comment: that's true..i guess it comes down to individual dev's taste then.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one having two scenarios::

```
1) Check all Checkboxes
1) UnCheck all Checkboxes
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjha999/4FsgE/1/)

Comment: I have seen that you have included a textbox in the demo. how do you clear the textbox?

Comment: `$('textboxId').val('');` this is how i would

Comment: @user3230425 If you want to clear each textboxes & the checkboxes the you should reset the form using reset button or $("Form").reset()

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use reset button for that purpose:

```
<input type="reset" />
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FsgE/)

---

If there are other fields too:

```
$('#unchk').click(function(){
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("checked",false);
    });
});
```

### [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ae28a/)

Comment: @Mr.Alien his current html contains only checkboxes

Comment: Users often omit other fields to make the question shorter so we can't really say :)

Comment: Ok then i will add an extra solution if bychance the user has other fields also

Comment: @Mr.Alien is correct i have only included the checkboxes and also i am looking for a function that will be in a button because the button would be a submit type.

Comment: @user3230425 i will add solution soon

Comment: This does not work for the code in the question, since it has no `form` element. And most real forms have other input elements beyond checkboxes.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela i added another solution

Answer (score 1):

You can go to http://jsfiddle.net/fh2nV/1/ link

or 
Sample Code below

Html :

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
    <th>Cell phone</th>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/></td>
    <td>BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/></td>
    <td>Samsung Galaxy</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="3"/></td>
    <td>Droid X</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/></td>
    <td>HTC Desire</td>

</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="5"/></td>
    <td>Apple iPhone 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a little bit of jQuery to achieve what you are looking to do.

`$("input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked").attr("checked",false)`

That should work. It isnt tested though and may not be syntactically correct. Just put in in a click listener for any element.

Comment: throwing error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'attr'`